# C++ STL-Map sort function

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to insert binary data into a B-Tree, implementing the STL interface. My typedefinition is the following:

```c
typedef btree::btree_map<unsigned char*, int, less<unsigned char*>, allocator<unsigned char*>, node_size> Tree;
```

The problem is that `less<unsigned char*>` do not compare the elements as I expect.

```c
Tree *bt = create_btree();

unsigned char *test = (unsigned char *) malloc(5);
unsigned char *test2 = (unsigned char *) malloc(5);

memset(test, 0, 5);
memset(test2, 0, 5);

cout << "Is equal: " << memcmp(test, test2, 5) << "\n";

memcpy(test + 0, "a\0", 2);
memcpy(test + 2, "HAM", 3);

memcpy(test2 + 0, "a\0", 2);
memcpy(test2 + 2, "HAM", 3);

bt->insert(make_pair(test, 1));
bt->insert(make_pair(test2, 2));

cout << "Is equal: " << memcmp(test, test2, 5) << "\n";


Tree::iterator iter;

for (iter = bt->begin(); iter != bt->end(); iter++) {

    cout << "Data: " << iter->first << " = " << iter->second << "\n";
}
```

When I run the code snippet above the function `memcmp` will return 0 which signals that both arrays are equal but the output of the programm is :

```c
Is equal: 0
Is equal: 0
Data: a = 1
Data: a = 2
```

I would expect that the second insert would overwrite the first, and only one line with `Data: a = 2` will be printed. I know that the key will be only printed till '\0' occurs. So here is the key in hex representation: `61 00 48 41 4d'.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it has something to do with the `less` operator.

My question is:
Is there a way to pass a function like `memcmp` to the map in order to compare the binary arrays correct.

Thank in advance

Comment: Of course it won't - because from C++ perspective `unsigned char*` is a raw C pointer, while strings are represented by `std::string`. I think you may pass lambda (C++11) or create a functor (before C++11) instead of `less`.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. I managed to implement a comparison function. But now the map keeps the value of the first insert but I want to replace the value if the same key is inserted again. Do you know where the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it has something to do with the less operator.

Correct. `less<T*>` function will compare pointers, not the content of array that might be pointed by them.

> Is there a way to pass a function like memcmp to the map in order to compare the binary arrays correct.

Yes, see the third template parameter and the first constructor parameter. You can pass a functor of your own choice (assuming `btree::btree_map` has the same interface as the `std::map`).

I would recommend using a `std::vector` or `std::string` as the key instead of a pointer. Not only do they work with `less<>`, but you also don't need to manage their memory.